# How to downgrade ubuntu 13.10 to 12.10?

Tags: 12.10

I really want to upgrade but if I do I need to be able to downgrade. I also want to know the spec are right for my system info.

System Info
 Memory 2.0 GiB
Processor Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz x 2
Graphics are Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR
OS type 32 bit
Disk 90.1 GB

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to revert an upgrade that didn't work out is by using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) to make an image of your disk or OS partition(s) before doing the upgrade; then you can restore the image to your disk or partition if and when you decide to do so. (Note that this works even if the disk has Windows on another partition, and it doesn't matter whether the partition(s) you're cloning are primary or logical.  Note also that it isn't necessary to clone your swap partition.)

Comment: Is there any other way than doing that. PLEASE

Comment: Why don't you want to use Clonezilla?  It's quite simple and surprisingly fast; for me, a complete image of one of my ~15-GB OS partitions takes perhaps twenty minutes to make, and it takes a similar amount of time to restore from one.  And a few quick taps on the keyboard.  There is also [Redo Backup and Recovery](http://redobackup.org/), which purports to be even simpler; I used it once, but I don't remember much about the experience.  I assume it works.